# DICOM Images from Visucam/Clarus software in ophthalmology with RGB Photometric Interpretation are displaying bluish

Tags: c#, dicom

In ophthalmology, Eye dicom images coming from Visucam software / Clarus software with Photometric Interpretation RGB are looking as blue when we export to our software.

To view these images we convert dicom to JPEG using pixel data of dicom images. When we view these converted JPEG images to our software it looks like bluish but the original images are in green or orange(Fundus) format.

can anyone help with this?
[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb3Qb.png)
[Display like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRx1f.png)

Comment: This question is way too broad and clearly shows no researches efforts. That would have been faster to use <your favorite search engine> and find the solution than typing this question.

Comment: I think you need to increase the resolution of the jPEG conversion.  The color change is probably due to lower resolution.  See WIKI : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the software that produces the DICOM files set the color space to "RGB" for images compressed using the baseline jpeg, but the color space for baseline jpeg images is assumed to be YBR.

Check the color space and the transfer syntax in the DICOM file: if it has a transfer syntax set to lossy jpeg and it specifies the color space as "RGB" then you found the problem.

Comment: Actually these are stereoscopic images, originally in JPS format. when we export these as a dicom it shows bluish.I have attached a link for original and bluish image in question.

Comment: @Nancy JPS is actually stereographic Jpeg: my guess is that the DICOM file has the wrong value in the tag Photometric Interpretation ((0028,0004): it is RGB but it should be YBR_FULL or YBR_PARTIAL. Some tools automatically correct for this common error, others don't.

Comment: Thanks! I changed Photometric Interpretation from RGB to YBR_FULL_422 and it worked.